# How to forward a specific log file in a syslog config?

Tags: debian, remote, syslog

I just want to ask how can I log for example /var/log/test/test.log to a remote syslog-ng?

Im using syslog not rsyslog. I can do it in rsyslog but not in syslog.

Answer (score 2):

Check the manual for your syslog version. Almost always you can forward ***the messages*** your systems generates via the syslog facility (which are normally written by syslog to local logfiles) to a remote syslog server, but not existing *log files* nor the files directly maintained by other services, that don't use a syslog facility.

In the syslog configuration file simply find the line that matches you existing log file e.g.:

```
 test.*               /var/log/test/test.log
```

and replace that by the ip-address of your remote server.

```
 test.*                @192.168.0.1
```

Many applications that by default maintain their own log files can be configured to use a syslog facility instead.

Comment: Hi HB, thanks for your quick response. I actually did that trick but still no luck. My syslogd version is 1.4.1 under old debian 5.